# How can I prevent fiberglass duct insulation from being blown into my living space?

Tags: hvac, furnace, central-air

For no explainable reasons (there are other materials that are not health hazard which provide sound insulation), manufacturers put fiberglass in the register boxes. I moved into a new, old, apartment. The air outlet where the air goes into the room looks like this:
[image]

Just by light touching with gloves, there are glass fibers on the glove, so despite the lies of the hvac companies, it does get into the air and one has to breath it. Additionally, the duct itself looks like this:
[image]
All that gray colour is dust. It all is blown into the room.

Anyone has an idea what to do? Mine are:

1. Put filter on one of the side of the outlet grill. I realise that it restricts the flow, bla bla bla...
2. I read, one can put a layer of latex mastic over the fiberglass but I am not sure, i found eg. epoxy sealer [here](https://www.tapplastics.com/product/fiberglass/epoxy_resins/coat_it_epoxy_sealer_with_kevlar/30) but i am not sure it helps or make things worse (i worry that if the consistency is too thick, i will be just grabbing fibers onto the brush and spreading that crap around. Also, i will have to breathe all the crap that is already in the duct.
3. Complete cut out the old fiberglass and replace it. But it is tough job and even tougher to get hands on the fiberglass board for a reasonable price, neither homedepot nor lowes sell that.
4. Cover this fiberglass with cardboard and seal the edges with silicone. Here, I am more worrier the purpose of the fiberglass as sound insulator would be lost and it would produce unpleasant sounds.

Any ideas? Anyone actually dealt with a similar issue? For me, at the moment, number 1 is the winner, it is the cheapest, lowest amount of work. On the other hand, i would like to do it properly while keeping at least some basic performance of that machine (I live in central Florida - Orlando)

---

**Adendum**
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: the duct is just dusty, which is perfectly normal. In fact all of this is quite normal; what the actual problem?

Comment: This sounds mostly like a rant. Please remove the accusations against "villainous companies out to get me", and focus on your actual concern and question.

Comment: This is standard HVAC duct board, that has been approved and in use for many decades.  I built my AC distribution system 35 years ago with this material.

Comment: [This picture](https://i.imgur.com/U4LO6vc.jpg) looks like there may be some mechanical damage to the board that _could_ be releasing some fibers. The rest of it looks perfectly good to me. There may be grounds for getting that one piece replaced _if_ you can blow fibers in the air with a desk fan (which would provide roughly the same air flow as the furnace fan does).

Comment: @dandavis I added three more pictures. The fiberglass insulation of the AC furnace door, infested with mold, another duct, the black thing at the back is most likely mold as well and glove after lightly touching one fiberglass panel in the duct, those fibers on the glove are glass fibers that will get in the air. So the issue is two fold, mold and shedding of fiberglass.

Comment: @FreeMan I added three more pictures, which show how easily it is to shed fiberglass, and mold inside the fiber glass.

Comment: Mechanically scraping the duct (with your finger) is far different than having air blowing along it. As I noted above, there does seem to be one panel that's been abraded, causing the fibers to be loose and those _might_ blow off with just the light air pressure of the furnace blower. All the other panels look perfectly good (if dirty) to me. Also, just because it's mold doesn't mean it's bad for you. There are millions of kinds of mold and they're not all instant death. Even if the furnace door were replaced, the new one would have the same fiberglass lining.

Comment: Also, heed [MonkeyZeus' advice](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/265026/34147) that since this is a rental, you have very little option to do anything about it yourself. Bring it up with your landlord.

Comment: Gravity will pull any glass insulation to the ground.   Don't futz with it, you may end up **causing** problems.

Comment: @SteveWellens This is not true, if it was, we would not be breathing any dust, pollen and other allergens would not be an issue either. Glass fibers are light enough to be in the air a significant amount of time (obviously, i am not talking about big chunks of fiberglass but individual fiber pieces). Yes, if you turn off ac and there is no disturbance for sufficiently long time, eventually, they settle but while it is blowing, they are floating around just like dust, pollen etc.

Comment: I didn't say dust and pollen.   If it is as bad as you think it is....you would be dead.

Comment: @SteveWellens Again, fiber glass can be very small on the size of dust and pollen and it will float for extended period of time. Even when it falls, it falls on the pillows and you end up breathing it. It can cause constant irritation the mucous membranes leading to their inflammation. Prolonged exposure can cause serious health issues. It does not cause death immediately. But it is a problem. Have you even ever handled fiber glass? Have you not felt itchy on you hands or back? Imagine this happening in your lungs.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**

The landlord needs to call a licensed HVAC company to fix or make modifications to the system.

The best way to go about getting the landlord to care is to present a medical need for cleaner air.

---

> For no explainable reasons ... manufacturers put fiberglass in the register boxes. I moved into a new, old, apartment.

False. The explanation is that [fiberglass duct](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WCAkT.jpg) is a thing and yours simply looks old.

> Put filter on one of the side of the outlet grill.

Since you rent, this is probably the only thing you could reasonably get away with doing.

> I read, one can put a layer of latex mastic over the fiberglass...

Mastic is a **very** thick paste. You would probably cause more damage than good.

You could probably spray some rubberized truck bed liner onto the fiberglass. Albeit, I'm not sure if it meets the UL 181 criteria for HVAC systems. A code inspector would probably have an issue with this.

> Complete cut out the old fiberglass and replace it. But it is tough job and even tougher to get hands on the fiberglass board for a reasonable price, neither homedepot nor lowes sell that.

As a tenant you very unlikely allowed to make such repairs to the apartment. If you can prove that you have difficulty breathing in your apartment then you *might* be able to get the landlord to properly fix things.

> Cover this fiberglass with cardboard and seal the edges with silicone. Here, I am more worrier the purpose of the fiberglass as sound insulator would be lost and it would produce unpleasant sounds.

The noise wouldn't likely change unless you have loose cardboard flapping around. The issue comes into play that you've now made the ductwork exponentially more flammable.

> So the issue is two fold, mold and shedding of fiberglass.

The ductwork needs to be replaced or cleaned; neither of which you'd be able to adequately perform given your budget and more importantly, the fact that you are a tenant.

Comment: Also of note, _any_ lining added to the inside of the duct work will reduce the inside dimension of the ducts and that will reduce airflow, making the fan work harder to push air, likely reducing its life span. It will also run longer to heat/cool to the desired temp, increasing the bill for running it.

Comment: @FreeMan True but that's not really a concern unless it's greater than 1/2" thick on all walls; tolerances are always built in.

Comment: Thank you @MonkeyZeus, i guess landlord is the only person that can solve it or me moving to a new place. I was just curious if there is something else i can do to avoid dealing with the landlord. Actually, I already put FPR 7 filter in one vent and a fpr1 over another and left two fully unrestricted to see what gets caught in them.

Comment: @atapaka You can pay to have the mold tested. If it's a hazardous variant then that's one way to force the landlord to remedy the issue. The likely outcome is that you will be forced to move out into temporary housing while the landlord gets the problem "fixed"; at best they'll spray some bleach in the duct and call it fixed. They could also drag their feet until you give up on trying to live there. Then it will be listed for rent again.